# readily lend themselves

Tags: phrase-meaning

Please let me know the meaning of the phrase below under quotes"".

We rarely collaborate because the projects don't "readily lend themselves" to teamwork.

Thanks
Ali

Comment: It means if you try to apply teamwork to these projects they don’t turn out very well.

Answer (score 1):

If a phrase appears difficult to understand, or translate, there's a good chance it might be an **[idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiom)** - a phrase whose meaning can't be easily deduced from the words alone.  They're an example of cultural knowledge, rather than purely language as such.

"lend themselves to" or "[lend itself to](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lend+itself+to)" is an idiom meaning "to be suited to", so if something "doesn't lend itself to something" then it means it's not suited to being used as that other thing or with that other thing.

If something appears to not translate easily, it could be an idiom, and you'll save yourself a lot of head-scratching by googling for it or searching somewhere like this site: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/

Answer (score 0):

The phrase itself, "readily lend themselves", could be defined as "very suited".

In the OP example, one could say "We rarely collaborate because the projects *are not very suited* to teamwork."

Comment: I do broadly agree with Livrecache and I'd add that *We rarely collaborate because the projects don't "readily lend themselves" to teamwork* is more obviously a strange fabrication than a useful example.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin The idiom is as common as dirt to me. Gardinias don't lend themselves to shearing the way boxwoods do. Are you saying you aren't familiar with the idiom, or that it sounds strange to you in this sentence?

Comment: Thanks, Phil, and are whether *lend themselves to* is a common phrase and whether *We rarely collaborate because the projects don't "readily lend themselves" to teamwork* the same question, in your book?